# Eclipse C/C++ doesn't run programm

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

Hi I was trying to run the standard Hello World code but I got only this in the console:

```
05:33:23 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Hello World ****
make all 
Building file: ../helloworld.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"helloworld.d" -MT"helloworld.d" -o "helloworld.o" "../helloworld.c"
Finished building: ../helloworld.c

Building target: Hello World.exe
Invoking: MinGW C Linker
gcc  -o "Hello World.exe"  ./helloworld.o   
Finished building target: Hello World.exe


05:33:25 Build Finished (took 2s.85ms)
```

I use MinGW and Eclipse Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
printf("Hello World again!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

That's the code I wrote.

Comment: How did you try to run the program in contrast to only building it (which seems to have succeeded)? Did you try to run the resuling .exe by executing it outside of Eclipse? Successfully or not?

Comment: If I try to open the .exe outside of Eclipse it only opens the cmd window for a ms and closes it directly.

Comment: Could that be what you program is doing? Is there anything in the program which would keep it open? A simple printf doesn't do that. Please make the experiment of opening a commandprompt and executing your program from  commandline there, it will keep the output visible.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. The log your provided is the build log. You need to explicitly configure Eclipse project and specify where your binary located, then you will be able to execute from within Eclipse, and even see the standard output.

Comment: As to regards why command window shows and disappears after a short period - this is normal behavior if you execute your binary from windows explorer. Since your application is console application, the window automatically closes when your program is terminated. If you want to see the actual result of what your program is printing - execute your application the command prompt.

Comment: Stupid question how I do that? I'm a newbie at programming and copy pasted the code only to try if eclipse works because I had a lot of other problems before with the compilation.

Comment: google : windows how to start cmd

Comment: i know how i get the cmd window but which command i have to use to run the .exe and what i have to program if i want the output in the console of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

the eclipse menu line contains the drop down menu: 'build' which you use to build the project.

the eclipse menu line contains the drop down menu: `run` which you use to run the executable.